# BFS Node counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, breadth-first-search

I'm new to Python and I have the BFS algorithm code below, this prints out the visited node

```
graph = {
  'A' : ['B','C'],
  'B' : ['D', 'E'],
  'C' : ['F'],
  'D' : [],
  'E' : ['F'],
  'F' : []
}

visited = [] # List to keep track of visited nodes.
queue = []     #Initialize a queue

def bfs(visited, graph, node):
  visited.append(node)
  queue.append(node)

  while queue:
    s = queue.pop(0)
    print (s, end = " ")

    for neighbour in graph[s]:
      if neighbour not in visited:
        visited.append(neighbour)
        queue.append(neighbour)


# Driver Code
bfs(visited, graph, 'A')
```

but I need to add a counter, that counts how many nodes is visited, how would I go about this?

Comment: Sidenote: a set would be better for `visited` (membership testing is much faster).

Answer (score 0):

You already have something that counts the number of visited nodes: the length of the `visited` list.

If you want the count, just do

```py
len(visited)
```

This is `O(1)` (constant time) since the list stores the length internally as an integer.